# Angular2 apply dynamic style to range control change event

Tags: angular, css, google-chrome, slider, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to apply different lower and upper fill color for input range slider control. In Edge, the CSS i use here works, but in chrome it needs some js script. Below is the code that i have. You can use codepen to verify this in both chrome and edge:

**Html:**

```
  <input class="slider" type="range"  value="60"/>
```

**CSS:** Included here separate styles to work for Edge and Chrome

```
/*Edge Css starts here*/
 _:-ms-lang(x), input[type=range] {
       -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 80%;
        padding-top: 25px;  
}
_:-ms-lang(x), .slider{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
_:-ms-lang(x), .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 15px;    
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #008C9B;
    cursor: pointer;
}
 _:-ms-lang(x), input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #008C9B;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
  _:-ms-lang(x), input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #91CED7;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
/*Removing default tooltip of slider*/
 _:-ms-lang(x), input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip { display: none; }

/*Edge Css ends here*/
/*Chrome Css Starts here*/
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { 
    .slider{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width:80%;
        height:10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #91CED7;
        outline: none;
    }
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 15px;    
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #008C9B;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

/*Chrome Css Ends here*/

**.js**

```
// Only for chrome
$( '.slider' ).on( 'input', function( ) {
    $( this ).css( 'background', 'linear-gradient(to right, #008C9B 0%, #008C9B '+this.value +'%, #91CED7 ' + this.value + '%, #91CED7 100%)' ); 
}  );
```

Here is what i need:

1. Use Angular2 code instead of using .js code.
2. I need to make this to work both in Edge and Chrome.

Currently Edge works as it doesnt need any script code to dynamically set the values in the slider but chrome needs some script to hook the change event of the slider so that applies the css % value to the linear gradient. Could anyone help to make this work in Angular2?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with by binding to background style and creating a template variable #slider.

```html
 <slider #slider
         class="slider"
         type="range"
         value="60" 
         [style.background]="'linear-gradient(to right, #008C9B 0%, #008C9B '+ slider.value +'%, #91CED7 ' + slider.value + '%, #91CED7 100%)'">
</slider>
```